# How to get a particular path from sdcard in android?

Tags: android

I have stored my video file here :-

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraVideo");

        if (! mediaStorageDir.exists()){

            if (! mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()){
                Log.d("MyCameraVideo", "Failed to create directory MyCameraVideo.");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Retrieve :-

```
videocursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                proj, null, null, null);
```

but, I am getting all the video files from sdcard, which I don't want. I want only the files stored in "MyCameraVideo" folder.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"%MyCameraVideo%"};
videocursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    parameters, selection, selectionArgs, null);
```